# Why is radical 13 (冂) called まきがまえ?

Tags: kanji, readings, radicals

Every source I used to look up names for this radical says it has 4: keigame, makigamae, dougamae and engamae. They all managed to explain pretty well what's the deal with every name except the 2nd one. All I managed to learn was that it's written with the radical itself despite the fact it can't be read as "maki". Can anyone please explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to

- [冂部](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%82%E9%83%A8)

According to the wikipedia article and the following, 冂 represents outskirts far from cities, there used to be a kun-reading in Japan まき(牧=farm), and that's why it is called まきがまえ.

- [「冂」という漢字](https://okjiten.jp/kanji2823.html)
- [冂←この漢字何て読むのですか？](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1016995390)

Comment: I looked up that kanji and it seems to mean "breed" more than anything. Are you sure it's the right one?

Comment: @Ray Which one? 冂  is not a common standalone kanji, so I don't really even if it can be a standalone. For 牧, see [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E7%89%A7/) for example.